# Yii2 не работает метод post при создании ссылкии

Tags: yii2, post

Создаю ссылку, у которо указан дата-метод, но при нажатии - все равно выкидывает ошибку про неразрешенный метод. crsf включен. шаблон basic, есть компонент dektrium yii2 user

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('Link Text', ['/user/logout'], [
                    'data'=>[
                        'method' => 'post',

                    ]
                ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так написать:

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('Link Text', ['/user/logout'], [
    'data-method' => 'post',
]) ?>
```